# mysql full-text search

Tags: mysql

Have a issue going on with mysql queries. I use full-text search.

I try to find exact match in my photo table, but problems occur.

Let us say I have a photo description like "Reodor Hansen have trouble with mysql"

IF I then search for a user named Reodor Mysql, the picture where Reodor Hansen is tagged in, will be visible.

Is there options to get a exact match? I now about quotes like  ' ' and " " but they are not helping me here.

Problem is that I don't wont Reodor Hansens photos visible in search when for Reodor Mysql.

Here is the query I use

SELECT * FROM _photos WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ( ' Reodor Mysql ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Further. Any idea how I can take this a step further? So I in the search box can write

"all pictures of Reodor Mysql" or  "show me the last 10 pictures Reodor Mysql uploaded"

and the search respond on this?

Comment: You can use (my) php library for this: https://github.com/alexschwarz89/easy-mysqli-fulltext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find an exact phrase, you could use double quotes. Just like this

```
SELECT * FROM _photos WHERE MATCH (description) 
                  AGAINST ( '"Reodor Mysql"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If you just want the last 10 pictures you could add a LIMIT to your query. Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM _photos WHERE MATCH (description) 
                  AGAINST ( '"Reodor Mysql"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                  ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC 
                  LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Any idea on how to solve my other question? How I can ask to see one users last X photos or where one user last was on vacation

Comment: I don't know how to answer your second question because I don't know how is your schema and your data. To answer that question I would need more information, for example: Where are you storing the upload date? Where are you storing users vacation ?. Fulltext is just a MySQL index that let you perform faster queries over a Text Column.

Answer (score 0):

If yo want an exact match of `Reodor Mysql` you will have to use the [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * FROM _photos WHERE description LIKE '%Reodor Mysql%'
```